# Electrostatics and Magnetostatics as Field Theories ( isn't the Coloumb law depicting an instantaneous action at a distance)

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, field-theory, magnetostatics

Take the formula for Coloumb's law. It does not show in any case as to how the static field propagates. What I can feel is that the field of a static charge is ever prevading from the time the charge was created and other charges interact with it.

But consider a static charge kept in your room. Now another charge in Andromeda galaxy should take some time to respond to the field of this charge ( if the field travels at c).

**Isn't Coloumb's law depicting an instantaneous action at a distance**

because

**But Coloumb's law is just like Newton's law, which Einstein desperately changed**.

*So how are Electrostatics and Magnetostatics in accord with the principle of relativity.*

**Their effect looks instantaneous.**

Comment: You first try to fix it up with retarded potentials, and then go full relativistic.

Comment: @JonCuster .. AI don't think so... First of all i read Retarded potentials for moving charges not static ones... Another - Panfosky in his book states the Field theoretical approach and retarded potentials are different

Comment: Have you studied the full set of Maxwell’s equations and their Lorentz covariance?

Comment: @G.Smith yes i have taken a 1st course in Electrodynamics just now.. But I don't understand how Electrostatics and Magnetostatics should be relativistically invariant when their equation is just the same as Newton's law of gravitation which was replaced. If it had to be replaced then why not electrostatics... "There should be a 1st time when the field of one static charge reraches the the other charge"...

Comment: Because Newtonian gravity assumes that the inverse square law holds regardless of the motions of the masses. This is not the case with Coulomb’s inverse square law, which holds only when the charges are at rest.

Comment: Exactly what @G.Smith said. How exactly are you defining "electrostatics"? As I mention in my answer below, in order for Coulomb's law to be true, the assumption is that all charges are in a steady state and unchanging. I believe this is called the electrostatic approximation. If you have a disturbance that you claim propagates, you are no longer in this regime, and Coulomb's law shouldn't be used anyway.

Comment: @G.Smith So if the earth were at rest relative to the sun ( being held into falling down into the sun by some great repulsive force) and if the the sun vanishes would the instantaneous movement of the earth be correct according to GR

Comment: The sun cannot vanish, so this is an unphysical and meaningless question.

Comment: And comments are not the place to ask new questions. Your question is about electrostatics and magnetostatics, not about GR.

Comment: @Shashaank I'm not sure what you're getting at with your previous statement, GR has nothing to do with this. As G.Smith said, your comparison of Coulomb's law and Newton's law is slightly flawed since -- while they share the same *form* -- the assumptions are different. While Newtonian gravity assumes the force to be given by the inverse square law irrespective of the motion of the object (which is false, and hence must be changed), Coulomb's law **only** works when the charges are always at rest, therefore it is already sufficiently restrictive. It can't be used when the fields change.

Comment: *I don't understand how Electrostatics and Magnetostatics should be relativistically invariant* They aren’t. For example, consider the electrostatic field of a point charge at rest. In a moving frame, there is no longer anything “electrostatic” about it. The particle is moving, and the field everywhere is dynamic.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean by a "static" field "propagating"!

But you're right that Coulomb's law *is* an example of an "action-at-a-distance" law. However, the reason we usually use this law is that we are often only considering *steady-state* situations, where the charge distributions do not change. In such cases, there are no "changes" in the system, and so no instantaneous propagation occurs.

Your example of a charge being created goes against this assumption, and thus you're right that Coulomb's law cannot be used here.

This is why for a consistent Lorentz-invariant theory, Electromagnetism is actually formulated using *fields*, which satisfy Maxwell's Equations:

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\nabla \cdot \mathbf{E} &= \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}\\
\nabla \cdot \mathbf{B} &= 0\\
\nabla \times \mathbf{B} &= \mu_0 \mathbf{j} + \frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial \mathbf{E}}{\partial t}\\
\nabla \times \mathbf{E} &= - \frac{\partial \mathbf{B}}{\partial t}\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

Taking the curls of the last two equations, you can show that the Electric and Magnetic Fields satisfy two non-homogeneous wave equations with speed $c$:

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\left( \nabla^2 - \frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}\right) \mathbf{E} &= \left(\frac{1}{\epsilon_0}\nabla\rho + \mu_0 \frac{\partial \mathbf{j}}{\partial t}\right),\\
\left( \nabla^2 - \frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}\right) \mathbf{B} &= -\mu_0(\nabla\times\mathbf{j}),\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

where the right hand sides of both equations act as the *sources* for these fields. This shows that disturbances in the fields propagate at the speed of light $c$.